# determine the sum of all positive odd integers up to some number

Tags: python

I tried this but it hackerearth does not accepts it. all test cases fail

```
def calculate(arr):
    return lambda arr: sum(xrange(1, arr + 1, 2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr_count = int(raw_input().strip())

    arr = []

    for _ in xrange(arr_count):
        arr_item = int(raw_input().strip())
        arr.append(arr_item)

    calculate(arr)
```

input:

```
3
1
2
3
```

expected output:

```
1
1
4
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's the point of the lambda that nothing happens with? Why not `return sum(xrange(1, arr + 1, 2))` directly? Even here, nothing is printed, so the code is dead. How are you supposed to give them output? Format needs some clarification here...

Comment: If you leave set up data here I'll try to take a look at it.

Comment: still all the test cases fail

Comment: The sum of the first `n` odd positive integers is `n**2`.

Comment: Sorry I meant in the form you are using in python like list = [3,1,2,3], it takes time to figure out how your data is formatted.

Comment: Added the sample input and output

Comment: Which task is it, I'll send you answers

Comment: `arr` is a list so it doesn't make sense to do `arr + 1`. Also, `lambda` defines a function, but you didn't do anything with that function so this code effectively does nothing.

Comment: @M3duZa I have added the task description. check

Comment: Are the result supposed to be printed ? returned? from `calculate` function?

Comment: @oldwooki I copied my code and the function below it, as it is like hackerrank

Comment: Is this problem not online and accessible on hackerearth, or why do you not provide a link to it?

Comment: @HeapOverflow It is my company's internal mock test

Comment: This is solvable with math.  For any number `n` the answer is `((n + 1) / 2) ** 2`.  Change `/` to `//` for Python 3.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski like this?     return lambda arr: sum(xrange((arr + 1) // 2) ** 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the task is to "print" the output one by one then, try the following:

```
def calculate(arr):
    for n in arr:
        print(((n+1)/2)) ** 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr_count = int(raw_input().strip())

    arr = []

    for _ in xrange(arr_count):
        arr_item = int(raw_input().strip())
        arr.append(arr_item)

    calculate(arr)
```

If the task is to return output list then, try the following:

```
def calculate(arr):
    return [((n+1)/2) ** 2 for n in arr]
...
```

Comment: Does the job. Awesome